# Dynamic Query in MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We all know we can create a dynamic select statement in SQL Server. for Eg :

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('ALF'), ('XYZ'), ('MNO'), ('BIG')
Select 'UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='''+a+''' WHERE Column_Name='''+a+'''  '  from t1
```

Above statement gives me below output in select

```
UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='ALF' WHERE Column_Name='ALF'
UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='XYZ' WHERE Column_Name='XYZ'
UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='MNO' WHERE Column_Name='MNO'
UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='BIG' WHERE Column_Name='BIG'
```

Now I can make sure dynamic generated query and can run on server.
Can such statement be created in mysql workbench?

Sql Fiddle example:

[image]

Comment: you can try using a procedure ( use prepare statement). In raw its not possible.

Comment: @Kaushik Thanks I heard we can achieve such using proc in MySQL but here the case is I don't have permission to create Proc.

Comment: *"you can try using a procedure ( use prepare statement). In raw its not possible."* @Kaushik  is wrong MySQL has [Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) which can be used without a procedure..

Comment: Oops my bad. Thanks @RaymondNijland for the information. :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland Updated The Query Have looke this might help you a clear view on what exactly i'm looking for

Comment: not sure what you mean or need in MySQL, as i do not fully understand or know what that SQL Server (MSSQL) SQL dialect code does..  See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: as for mine idea it feels more like you are looking for MySQL's *"upsert"* -> `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` syntax.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Update The Question with sql fiddle example here i have table containing 4 rows and Getting a dynamic update statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to run a query in MySQL that will output a series of sql update statements. Essentially, you are asking for an SQL Server => MySQL translation of this line:

```
Select 'UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='''+a+''' WHERE Column_Name='''+a+'''  '  from t1
```

One MySQL option is the concat function:

```
Select concat("UPDATE TABLE t1 SET A='",a,"' WHERE Column_Name='",a,"'") from t1
```

Comment: Thanks Man exactly was looking something like this